# Facebook DeepLink - не получается подключить

Tags: java, android, android-studio, facebooksdk

Нужно передавать deeplink в WEbView, чтобы к ссылки подставлялся саб аккаунт, например "?sub_id_1=yandex" ... Подключаю Facebook следующим образом в MainActivity:

```java
        FacebookSdk.setAutoInitEnabled(true);
        FacebookSdk.fullyInitialize();
        AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this,
                new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                        // Process app link data
                        if (appLinkData != null) {
                            Bundle bundle = appLinkData.getArgumentBundle();
                            Log.i("DEBUG_FACEBOOK_SDK", bundle.toString());
                        } else {
                            Log.i("DEBUG_FACEBOOK_SDK", "AppLinkData is Null");
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
```

В манифесте указываю как на примере из документации

```java
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
*****
****

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter android:label="11">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
                <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="22">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
                <data android:scheme="example"
                    android:host="gizmos" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Далее в настройках URL передачи для запуска в Android Studio указываю "example://gizmos" .. Но передача не происходит и выдаёт "AppLinkData is Null"

Что то у меня такое чувство что я всё понапутал. Помогите кто сможет советом или направлением или решением. Спасибо!

Comment: Интернет в манифесте разрешили?

Comment: Конечно разрешил!

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос все разрешения в манифесте. В панели девелопера ФБ все три галочки зеленые?

Comment: Да, "Отложенная глубокая ссылка" крестиком( Разрешенией 3 -     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Запускаете на эмуляторе? Нужно запускать там, где стоит приложение ФБ и вы авторизованы.

Comment: Прямая отправка отлично работает на эмуляторе, после установки Facebook на эмуляторе .. А вот отложенная не срабатывает ... "AppLinkData is Null" выдаёт всё равно